# I want to name my columns the numbers from 2 for loops

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am running a double for loop of the form

```
for i in range (0,5):
    for j in range (0,5):
        colname = '%i%j' %{'i':'i','j':'j'}
        df[colname] = poisson.pmf(i,df['lambda'])*poisson.pmf(j,df['mu'])
```

I would like for the code to return the 36 extra columns of 00 up to 55

but i get the following error

> TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not dict

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: are u facing error in line 3?

Comment: No idea what language this is, definitely not Python.

Comment: @polku: yes it is Python...

Comment: colname = '%i%j' %{'i':'i','j':'j'} is where the error comes in

Comment: Do you want `colname = '%d%d' % (i, j)`?

Comment: you can do like colname = '%d%d' %(i,j)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `range(6)` and `%d`:

```
for i in range (6):
    for j in range (6):
        colname = '%d%d' % (i, j)
        print (colname)
```

```
00
01
02
03
04
05
10
11
12
13
14
15
20
21
22
23
24
25
30
31
32
33
34
35
40
41
42
43
44
45
50
51
52
53
54
55
```